# Fortran compilation dependency of modules and INCLUDE statement with make

Tags: makefile, fortran, include, gnu-make

I am compiling Fortran sources with MinGW and make on Windows.

Source file extensions are `.f` and `.for` - the `.for` are ones that are modules (some `.for` files even contain multiple modules).

I had a generic makefile ; it basically was

```
# Source directories
dirs := . srkf

# Executable to create
Executable = D:\Executables\a.exe
# -------------------------------------------------------

# Obj dir
Objets_dir = ../obj

VPATH = $(dirs) $(Objets_dir)

# Creation of .for list
Sourmod := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.for))

# Creation of .f list
Sources := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.f))

# Obj list
Objmod = $(patsubst %.for,%.o,$(Sourmod))
Objets = $(patsubst %.f,%.o,$(Sources))

# Full path to .o
TempObjets = $(addprefix $(Objets_dir)/, $(notdir $(Objmod) $(Objets)))

    
# Comp options
cpl = gfortran
cpl_opt = -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -O3 -Wall
lnk = gfortran
lnk_opt = 

# Compilation
$(Objets_dir)/%.o:%.for
    $(cpl) -J$(Objets_dir) $(cpl_opt) -c $< -o $(Objets_dir)\$(notdir $@)
$(Objets_dir)/%.o:%.f
    $(cpl) -I$(Objets_dir) $(cpl_opt) -c $< -o $(Objets_dir)\$(notdir $@)

# Link
$(Executable): $(TempObjets)
    $(lnk) -o $@ $^ $(lnk_opt)

clean:
    @-rm -rf $(Objets_dir) $(Executable)
```

Modules are compiled first, but :

- editing and updating a .for file does not lead to .f files using a module contained in said .for file to be recompiled, and
- there is a small part of the project where due to external constraints, I will be required to use some (elementary) `include` statements (and not modules, although i will still use modules everywhere else), and the same kind of dependency problem arises. If I have a `foo.f` file with an `include 'bar.inc'` somewhere, then modifying the `bar.inc` file and compiling the code does not lead to `foo.f` being recompiled.

This is obviously problematic. How would you this makefile, so that BOTH behaviors / kind of dependencies are taken into account ?

Edit : it turns out the following solution, which has been provided to me, solves issues in both cases :

```
# Source directories
dirs := . srkf

# Executable to create
Executable = D:\Executables\a.exe
# -------------------------------------------------------

# Obj dir
Objets_dir ?= ../obj

VPATH = $(dirs) $(Objets_dir)

# Creation of .for list
Sourmod := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.for))

# Creation of .f list
Sources := $(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.f))

# Obj list
Objmod = $(patsubst %.for,%.o,$(Sourmod))
Objets = $(patsubst %.f,%.o,$(Sources))

# Full path to .o
TempObjets = $(addprefix $(Objets_dir)/, $(notdir $(Objmod) $(Objets)))
DEPENDS = $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(TempObjets))

# Comp options
cpl = gfortran
FFLAGS = -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -O3 -Wall
lnk = gfortran
lnk_opt = 

all: $(Executable)

# Compilation
$(Objets_dir)/%.o:%.for
    $(cpl) -J$(Objets_dir) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(Objets_dir)/%.o:%.f
    $(cpl) -I$(Objets_dir) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(Objets_dir)/%.d: %.for
    @-(echo -n $(Objets_dir)/;$(cpl) -cpp -MM -J$(Objets_dir) -fsyntax-only $(FFLAGS) -c $<) > $@

$(Objets_dir)/%.d: %.f
    @-(echo -n $(Objets_dir)/;$(cpl) -cpp -MM -I$(Objets_dir) -fsyntax-only $(FFLAGS) -c $<) > $@

-include $(DEPENDS)

# Link
$(Executable): $(TempObjets)
    $(lnk) $(lnk_opt) -o $@ $^

# Clean
clean:
    @-rm -rf $(Objets_dir)/* $(Executable)

#all:
#   @echo $(value Sources)
#   @echo $(value Objets)
#   @echo $(value TempObjets)
```

This indeed works both for includes (modifying the `bar.inc` file and compiling the code does now lead to `foo.f` being recompiled) as well as for modules.

gfortran (or make ?) seems actually quite smart. In the case of modules for example, if you edit and save a module, and then ask for a compilaton, it will (of course) recompile the module, but it will recompile other sources that depend on it ONLY if the resulting .mod file differs. I sure didn't expect that it would be this smart (I expected i to trigger a new compilation of dependent files as long as one of the upstream file was recompiled).

Comment: _and a .f file will get automatically recompiled if a module it is using has been modified, so this is great._  I don't believe it.  At least, there is nothing at all in the makefile you've provided that would cause this to happen.  Make doesn't know anything about code except how to build it.  If there is some relationship between source files that means some source files must be rebuilt if other source files change, you HAVE to put it into the makefile explicitly.

Comment: @MadScientist You are entirely right. I am very confused because this is something I recently checked. But you are right, it indeed doesnt. Sorry, I will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the Fortran (`.f`) files to be rebuilt whenever any of the module (`.for`) files is rebuilt, just make these changes to your makefile:

```
# Obj target lists
Objmod = $(patsubst %.for,$(Objets_dir)/%.o,$(notdir $(Sourmod)))
Objets = $(patsubst %.f,$(Objets_dir)/%.o,$(notdir $(Sources)))

# All objects
TempObjets = $(Objmod) $(Objets)

# Make sure all .f objects are rebuilt after any .for objects are built
$(Objets) : $(Objmod)
```

Comment: Thanks. I only want a modification on a file to trigger recompilation of relevant files (ones that do use the corresponding module(s)), not all of them.

Comment: There is no way for make to know that.  If you want make to know that, you have to tell it which files use which modules.  Make can't parse your files or understand the syntax of Fortran files, itself.

Comment: Yes. The second makefiles instructs gfortran to produce dependencies, and the end result is a functional solution for include files. Modifying one of them triggers relevant recompilation with the second makefile. Is there no way to instruct gfortran to produce the same kind of dependencies regarding modules so that the same behavior is obtained ?

Comment: I don't know.  You'll have to look at the documentation for the Fortran compiler you're using to find out if there are options that will generate module dependencies in addition to include dependencies.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at https://linux.die.net/man/1/makedepf90  Maybe you can find a version of that tool that will work on Windows.

Comment: Using make for modern Fortran in 2020s is a strange way to make things complicated for you. There are many buld tools that consider dependencies  between modules automatically.